# Base classes shouldn't have memberwise copy?

Tags: c++

I'm reading Stroustrup's *A Tour of C++*, and in it there's a line:

> To complement `=default`, we have `=delete` to indicate that an operation is not to be generated. A base class in a class hierarchy is the classical example where we don't want to allow a memberwise copy.

As someone new to copy/move semantics, I'm having trouble understanding why base classes wouldn't want to have a memberwise copy. I would think that the base class would be responsible for copying its members and the derived class would be responsible for copying the rest. Any examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might just mean that's an easy way to ensure all derived classes will be noncopyable.

Comment: I suppose there is some context to this quote. Per se `=default` is not only for copy/move so that quote probably refers to text that comes before

Comment: Sorry to confuse by not including the complete context - the quote is proceeded with an example that just shows a base class with the copy operations marked with `=delete` to show that this example base class is non-copyable — doesn't elaborate further on why this is the case for base classes.

Comment: It does say, however, "When a class has a pointer member, it is usually a good idea to be explicit about copy and move operations. The reason is that a pointer may point to something that the class needs to delete, in which case the default memberwise copy would be wrong."

Comment: one way to read it is "A base class in a class hierarchy is the classical example where we potentially want to disallow a memberwise copy.", ie not all bases should `delete` those members, but a base that cannot be copied is a good example where `=delete` is the right tool to make it non-copyable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it doesn't always make sense.

If you have a class say, `Person` with simple fields, it makes sense to have some kind of a default copy/move constructor.  It's a data class after all.

Where this breaks down is when your class is operating with some other kind of resource such as streams, database connections, sockets etc, which you don't really want copied - so we prevent errors by telling the compiler not to implement a default copy for this (although a move might be just fine).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I suppose I interpreted the statement as a declaration: "a base class should not allow memberwise copy", but it seems like, as you said, there would be valid use cases like with `Person`.

Comment: what you wrote is not wrong, but it doesnt explain fully the quote. Just because some derived cannot be copied isnt a reason to make every base class non-copyable.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, it's a good way to prevent accidental slicing, because attempts to do so will result in a compilation error.

On the other, I think you're right: that risk is a small price to pay for the ability to put the various "pieces" of the overall copy operation into the most sensible place. I can't think why I'd want a derived class to be responsible for actioning the copying of base members. Or, come to think of it, perhaps this would prevent the entire hierarchy from being copyable in the first place.

If the base class is completely empty (has no data members, only functions), then I suppose it's more reasonable.

Personally I only *ever* delete a copy constructor if I want the thing to be non-copyable full stop.